# Precision/Recall against threshold curve not useful in improving model performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, precision-recall, threshold

I am doing fraud detection (binary classification) on an unbalanced credit dataset, using SVM. My current precision is 5% while recall is 90%. (I am using undersampling to train and test a model from original data's training set, and predicting on original data's test set)

The Precision/Recall against threshold curve is quite weird when testing the model on the undersampled data:

[image]

The Precision/Recall against threshold curve for predicting on original test data shows ~0.45 value at the intersection of the precision and recall line.

[image]

I expected that if i used predict_probability > threshold then 1, else 0 values in my confusion matrix, i would get a recall and precision of ~0.45.

However, it turns out recall is now 85% but precision 11%.

I've some questions below:

1) Why isn't it ~45% recall and ~45% precision like the curve shows?

2) If not , what is the use of the curve?

When i increased the threshold above 0.45, it actually gives better precision. Like this, do i just trial and error to find optimal threshold where precision is similar to recall?

edit addon:
I am using linear kernel SVM from sklearn.

```
classifier= svm.SVC(C= 1, kernel= 'linear', random_state= 0, class_weight='balanced')
```

Code for precision and recall (i had 1 for undersampled test data, 1 for original test data)

```
precision, recall, th = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_pred)
```

This is the graph code (gives a curve rather than line when using other models as expected)

```
plt.plot(th, precision[1:], label="Precision",linewidth=5) 
plt.plot(th, recall[1:], label="Recall",linewidth=5) 
plt.title('Precision and recall for different threshold values') 
plt.xlabel('Threshold') 
plt.ylabel('Precision/Recall') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that created this plot? They look suspiciously linear.

Comment: @usεr11852 yea im using a linear SVM from sklearn. 
This is the graph code (gives a curve rather than line when using other models as expected)

plt.plot(th, precision[1:], label="Precision",linewidth=5) 
plt.plot(th, recall[1:], label="Recall",linewidth=5) 
plt.title('Precision and recall for different threshold values') 
plt.xlabel('Threshold') 
plt.ylabel('Precision/Recall') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I was mostly referring to how `precision` and `recall` have been calculated. :)

Comment: Balancing precision and recall is not a good measure for fraud detection. The cost of not detecting fraud is usually *much* higher then the cost of other results.

Comment: @Tim: I would argue the opposite. The cost of a fraudulent transaction is probably smaller than disallowing high valued legal transactions. Which in itself highlights that a cost-sensitivity approach is more relevant overall.

Comment: @usεr11852 pretty standard haha. adding in the question as well!